# How to convert a graph to a straight line using Log scales in excel?

Tags: functions, logarithms, graphing-functions

How to convert a graph to a straight line using Log scales in excel?

Is there a way to convert a graph plot to a straight line graph, using logarithmic scales on both axes.

[Graph Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEpL5.jpg)

Comment: It's a little unclear what you want exactly. You can try changing one or both of the axes to logarithmic in order to make the graph look like a line. But surely, you don't want to modify the data, or ... ?

Comment: So is your question about how to use Excel (how to change the axes) or how to modify the data, or ... ?

Comment: @Matti P. Thanks for the prompt response, I do not want to change the data.

Comment: So just go to the axis range settings and change the range to logarithmic. Maybe it will result in a more "linear" graph, maybe not. But this is, I think, everything you can do at this stage. What's the difficulty you are facing?

Comment: @Matti P . Can you can make the graph perfectly linear? I would like to do this to verify the relationship on the photo above.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what was the result? Did you try to change the axes?